# How to get list element from rosparam parameter from the cmd?

Tags: ros

I loaded this yaml file:

```
num_boxes: 1
boxes: [[x: 0.349, y: 0.213, z: 0.117]]
```

with `rosparam load my_config.yaml` then I can do `rosparam get boxes` and get:

```
- - {x: 0.349}
  - {y: 0.213}
  - {z: 0.117}
```

But how can I access only the first list or elements in the second list? I tried boxes[0], boxes(0) and boxes{0} but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'm answering it because it's still useful to put an answer here.

Using the example given, `boxes` is a list of lists ([YAML syntax](https://wiki.ros.org/YAML%20Overview)). From the [`rosparam`](https://wiki.ros.org/rosparam) command line tool, ***we can't*** process `rosparam get /boxes` any further (excepting `grep` and regex). In common use, we can access the Parameter Server in [C++](https://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists) / [Python](https://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server).

```py
# Python
>>> import rospy
>>> boxes = rospy.get_param("/boxes"); boxes
[[{'x': 0.349}, {'y': 0.213}, {'z': 0.117}]]
# Boxes is a python list/array of list of dicts
>>> boxes[0]
[{'x': 0.349}, {'y': 0.213}, {'z': 0.117}]
>>> boxes[0][0]
{'x': 0.349}
```

```cpp
// C++
#include <vector>
#include <ros/ros.h>
// yaml_list: [1, 2]
ros::NodeHandle *nh;
std::vector<int> yaml_list;
double x = 0.0;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_params_node");
  nh = new ros::NodeHandle("");
  nh->getParam("/yaml_list", yaml_list);
  x = yaml_list[0];
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

To have deeper data structures, such as vectors of vectors of maps, you have to use the xmlrpcpp ([.h](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/utilities/xmlrpcpp/include/xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcValue.h)/[.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/utilities/xmlrpcpp/src/XmlRpcValue.cpp)) interface.

```cpp
// C++
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcValue.h> // catkin component
ros::NodeHandle *nh;
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue boxes; // std::vector<std::vector<std::map<std::string,double>>>
double x = 0.0;
int i = 0;
double point[3] = {0};
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "get_params_node");
  nh = new ros::NodeHandle("");
  nh->getParam("/boxes", boxes);
  if(boxes.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::Type::TypeArray && boxes.size() > 0){
    // boxes[0] is a 'TypeArray' aka vector
    if(boxes[0].getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::Type::TypeArray && boxes[0].size() > 0){
      // boxes[0][0] is a 'TypeStruct' aka map
      if(boxes[0][0].getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::Type::TypeStruct && boxes[0][0].hasMember("x")){
        x = double(boxes[0][0]["x"]);
        for(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::iterator it = boxes[0][0].begin(); it != boxes[0][0].end(); ++it){
          point[i++] = double(*it);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

In standard use, the [`<rosparam>`](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) XML tag keeps the same YAML or `rosparam` command line syntax.