# how to access yaml map data in ros

Tags: localization, grid, mapping, ros

I am going to write my localization node; for that, I need to access the occupancy grid map data, which I have already saved in YAML format. How can I access the data of the YAML map? For example, I want to know my map's value of (10,1). If it is impossible to access data in YAML format, how can I get that data and use it for localization?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a more specific yaml library to either Python/C++, whichever you're using (ex pyyaml, yaml-cpp).

In ros, you can load the yaml file in the launch file using a rosparam element: `<rosparam file="$(find my_pkg)/config/my_map.yaml"/>`. If you want it to be a private param of a class (recommended in general), put the element within the `<node>..</node>`.
To access it in python/c++, read it like a normal parameter. In python, it'll probably be simple, as an array-array index. In C++, you'll use the XmlRpc type, which will resolve to vector-vector index.
[See this answer for more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367004/6069586)